# What metric(s) is a good proxy for relatedness?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics, evolutionary-game-theory

In attempting to seed a simulation, where an individual foregoes resources that go r to same-type individuals and (1-r) to all members (including same-type individuals).  What commonly used metrics are a good proxy for r in this sense?  In other words, if I am seeing a simulation to replicate the parameters of the mean population for, for example, a zebra finch or a human or a house mouse, and I am looking in empirical reports of these species and r does not appear, are there other metrics that are convertible?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are looking for. Are you seeking for a way to calculate genetic relatedness? If `r`is a value for giving food to `same-type` individuals how do you define `same-type`? Is it from genetic relatedness or other way?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  No I'm not looking for a way to calculate genetic relatedness.  I have written a simulation and am looking to feed it realistic values for relatedness.  Emphasis upon populations of the zebra finch, human, house mouse, and also populations of trees.  But r is not reported commonly and other metrics are reported more typically, such as FST.  I don't know whether they are substitutable or convertible into r.

Comment: This article by Harpending would suggest that but I'm not seeing it in a textbook and am not familiar enough with these measures. Harpending, Henry (2002-11-01). "Kinship and Population Subdivision" (PDF). Population & Environment. 24 (2): 141–147. @Untitpoi

Comment: It would seem from the article, unless I am wrong, that 2*Fst is a good proxy for the Hamiltonian r (if benefits can be confined to within subpopulation).  Am I wrong?  @Remi.b